# Merging two html table in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to merge two html table in jquery.I want to merge the table tbl1 and tbl2 and recreate a table joined.I just want to copy the tag not to cut the tag.need to have 3 tables
I have tried as

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('#tbl2 thead tr').find('th').insertAfter('#joined thead tr');
$('#tbl1 thead tr').find('th').insertAfter('#joined thead tr');
$('#tbl2 tbody tr').wrap('#joined tbody tr');
$('#tbl1 tbody tr').wrap('#joined tbody tr');

});
```

```css
#joined{background:#ff0;margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<table id="joined"><thead><tr></tr><thead>
<tbody><tr></tr><tbody>
</table>
<table id="tbl1">
<thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
      <tr>
         <th>Opportunity</th>
         <th>Pipeline Count</th>
         <th>Pipeline Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>1595050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>4573200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>1193328</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tbl2">
   <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
      <tr>
         <th>Opportunity</th>
         <th>Pipeline Count</th>
         <th>Pipeline Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>TEst</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>1595050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>TEst</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>4573200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>TEst Submitted</td>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>1193328</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need  the html table as

```html
<table id="joined">
<thead >
      <tr>
         <th>Opportunity</th>
         <th>Pipeline Count</th>
         <th>Pipeline Value</th>
         <th></th> <!-- empty cell -->
         <th>Opportunity</th>
         <th>Pipeline Count</th>
         <th>Pipeline Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>1595050</td>
         <td></td> <!-- empty cell -->
         <td>TEst</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>1595050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>4573200</td>
         <td></td> <!-- empty cell -->
         <td>TEst</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>4573200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>1193328</td>
         <td></td> <!-- empty cell -->
         <td>TEst Submitted</td>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>1193328</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate whats that sentence means *I just want to copy the tag not to cut the tag* what tag you want to copy? Do you want to merge both tables data or table headers into third table in a stack? or side by side?

Comment: I want to append the tag in joined and don't want to insertAfter